# Obtaining cms component data inside slot

Tags: spartacus-storefront

We are trying to style an existing slot (SiteLinks) that contain a number of CMSLinkComponents. We are failing to obtain the full data of the components, because we are only receive the `uid` and `typeCode` when we use `let-[var]` syntax on the ng-template.

Are there example of how to access the full data for these components, without requesting them separately based on the `uid`?

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteLinks" let-data>
  <pre>{{ data.components$ | async | json }}</pre>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context model depends on where outlets are used. In your case context is a Slot model, and on this level of hierarchy you have only list of components and not their data, because data you should get separately.

I believe, this approach will work:

```
<ng-template cxOutletRef="SiteLinks" let-slot>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let component of (slot.components$ | async)">
    <ng-container [cxComponentWrapper]="component"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

`cxComponentWrapper` also can be helpful in cases when you need handle nested components.

Comment: Thank you Artem. This works for us, altough we pass the component into another component as an `@Input()` and request more data afterwards.